# How can I install the Unity Photo Lens

Tags: installation, unity, lenses, photo

I can't install the Photo Lens. After running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-photo unity-scope-shotwell unity-scope-flickr
```

I get this:

> Package unity-lens-photo is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'unity-lens-photo' has no installation candidate

Is there a fix for that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you running?  It sounds like it's not built for your version yet.

Comment: Hi @Chris. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. I believe it should work anyways.

Answer (score 1):

After a brief look at https://launchpad.net/~scopes-packagers/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=, it seems that there is no package named unity-lens-photo. It looks like  unity-lens-photos, however is in the main archive for quantal (12.10) but not for precise (12.04).

If you really want it in 12.04, you could update your unity to the quantal version with this ppa (https://launchpad.net/~benkai/+archive/precise-unity-backport) although that could be a bit risky as it is still in beta.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for your help. It sounds very reasonable. I have one more question... will I obligatorily have to update Unity to the Quantal version anyway someday or not? I'm planning to use 12.04 LTS for at least for 2 or 3 years.

And the last thing. If I do what you say in order to see if that's the problem, can I safely go back to the actual Unity version? Thanks!

Comment: A friend didn't have problems in 12.04. It's in spanish but look his output:

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise
linuxnoveles1@linuxnovelesVB:~$ sudo apt-get install unity-lens-photo unity-scope-flickr
Leyendo lista de paquetes… Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado… Hecho
unity-scope-flickr ya está en su versión más reciente.
unity-lens-photo ya está en su versión más reciente.
0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 26 no actualizados.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, unity-lens-photos is not available in the scopes-packagers PPA.  However, you can download a .deb file containing `unity-lens-photos` from [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~scopes-packagers/+archive/ppa/+build/3244463/+files/unity-lens-photo_0.1-0~12~precise1_all.deb).  Double click on the downloaded file to install the lens.

You will still need to install the `unity-scope-shotwell` and `unity-scope-flickr` packages (from the PPA) in order to provide sources for the lens to search and log out and back in again in order to activate the lens.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install Unity Photo Lens on Ubuntu 12.04, I had to install the deb package found [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webapps_preview/precise/main/base/unity-lens-photo). That solved the Flickr problem but not the Shotwell functionality.

Answer (score -1):

unity-lens-photo separately download the DEB package to install later, and at the end: 
 sudo add- apt-repository ppa: scopes-packagers/ppa 
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt- get install unity-lens-photo unity-scope- Shotwell unity-scope- flickr 
 for me it works 
 P.S. 
 Some of the packages that are needed and there is no time, unfortunately, is not easy to separately download:)? 
 I greet